# What is the common solution to setup Eclipse for team development?

Tags: eclipse, installation

1. Should every team member create his or her own workspace and import project stored under source control? Or is there a way to put workspace under source control too?
2. How to avoid using absolute paths in workspace configuration?
3. Are there other bottlenecks in this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One route people take is to generate the Eclipse projects from the build file.  This has an added benefit if the development environment is designed to not have a rigid structure (e.g. the path to library X can be relatively different in environment Y than in environment Z) since the same configuration data (files, environment variables, etc) can be used to set up the Eclipse project as the non-Eclipse environment.

Answer (score 3):

I would not put Workspaces into SCM; that would demand that each developer's environment be identical. Instead take care to avoid any hard-coded paths; use workspace variables.

Use [Project Set Files](http://wiki.eclipse.org/PSF) to identify and share sets of projects that need to be imported to a Workspace. These files can/should be kept in SCM, perhaps in dedicated release projects.

My practice when doing serious work on an application is to start with a clean workspace, no extraneous projects. Populate it using the PSF.

Comment: As I understood "Project Set Files" feature works only with CSV, this is not appropriate for me.